# How to solve series that produces i

Tags: complex-numbers, summation

[image]

I can find that it converges due to the A.S.T, but I how do you solve for this answer that wolframaplha produces?

Comment: That is an approximation to a real number. They just haven't implemented dropping the imaginary part when what they are computing is real.

Comment: Put $y = 1/(3-x) + 2/(1+x) + 1/(5+x) + 4/(7-x)$ in Wolfram Alpha, look at the sections 'Real Roots' and 'Complex Roots' and laugh.

Comment: What is suprizing is that, using another CAS, the numerical value of the infinite sum looks to be $3.6971995888917$ and the result you give seems to correspond to a summation up to $n=200$ !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sum is a real number, as any sum with all real terms is real. Notice that $10^{-13}$ is really really small. That’s showing up due to the numerical approximation methods used to solve problems like this.